# jmds. ansichtig werden

Tags: genitive, passive

> Jetzt wurde die alte Frau seiner ansichtig

Ich verstehe nicht, was sich aufs Agens des Sehens bei dieser passiven Struktur bezieht, die Phrase im Nominativ oder die im Genitiv. Wer erblickt wen?

Comment: Es handelt sich nicht um ein Passiv! *ansichtig* ist kein Partizip II, sondern ein Adjektiv.

Comment: Danke für die Korrektur @DavidVogt!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normalerweise regiert im Deutschen entweder ein Verb oder eine Präposition den Kasus. Es gibt aber auch eine Reihe von Adjektiven, die zwingend einen bestimmten Fall erfordern, so auch eine Reihe von *Adjektiven*, die den Genitiv regieren - *ansichtig* ist eins davon, von denen viele ursprünglich wohl Partizipformen waren und daher auch eine Tätigkeit bzw. den Endzustand einer Tätigkeit beschreiben können.

*bewußt* oder *eingedenk* sind andere solche Beispiele.

Der Aktor ist bei diesen Adjektiven immer das Substantiv, das mit diesem Adjektiv näher beschrieben ist.

> Ich bin mir der Tatsache bewußt, dass 1 plus 1 2 ergibt

Hier weiß *ich* etwas

> Er war des Autofahrens unkundig

Hier wusste *er* nicht, wie man Auto fährt

> Sie wurde seiner ansichtig

*Sie* hat ihn gesehen

> Ungeachtet der Tatsache, dass Strom gefährlich ist, fasste er trotzdem an die Steckdose

*Er* beachtete die Tatsache nicht.

Solche Konstrukte werden heute zunehmend für altmodisch betrachtet und kommen noch in stehenden Wendungen ("Sie ist des Lebens froh"), sehr gehobener Sprache und oft auch noch im Amts- und Juristendeutsch ("Eingedenk der vorliegenden Indizien hält das Gericht den Angeklagten für des Verbrechens überführt") vor.

Answer (score 6):

[Der Duden schreibt zu ansichtig:](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ansichtig)

> Er erschrak, als er des Feuerscheins ansichtig wurde.

Das Genitivsupplement ist also das bemerkte Etwas. Das heißt in deinem Fall:

> Jetzt wurde die alte Frau seiner ansichtig.
>
> Jetzt bemerkte/sah die alte Frau ihn.